# Can material outposts cause a daily net gain of materials?

Tags: state-of-decay

It seems the rarest of all resources is materials, especially if you move your base.  Can setting up all of your outposts to be materials outposts cause a net daily gain of materials?

Comment: This did not seem to be true from my own experiments.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Of course it depends on how much you are using.
Your use of material will be pretty high during construction and for a while after.

Answer (score 1):

Each resource outpost consumes one construction material to create three of the resource type per day.

A construction material outpost does the same thing. When you create one of these outposts, you should see your daily materials usage reduce by 2. This is because it is using one material to produce three. 3 - 1 = 2.

If you had *all* construction outposts then the outposts should result in a net gain, but I haven't personally tried it. It probably pulls the materials from your stash, so I would expect you would need to keep as many materials around as you have outposts for it to keep working.

However, since you can only have 8 outposts, and each one can only produce 2 per day, you could only get 16 materials per day from your outposts. This might not be enough to cover your daily usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you gain more from that outpost than your survivors use daily, then yes. It might help to have more than one material in each outpost.